# Streamwriter for output for excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, streamwriter

I'm trying to export some data into an Excel file using streamwriter. I'm trying to edit what I'm using for exporting data in .csv but editing it in such way. What I want to export, in the .xls file, is Listbox1 in the first column and Listbox2 in the second one.

```
        Using writer = New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
            For Each o As String In Form3.ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object).Zip(Form3.ListBox2.Items.Cast(Of Object), Function(x1, x2) x1 & " " & x2)
                writer.WriteLine(o)
            Next
        End Using
```

Obviously it exports data in the same cell, just putting a backspace between the two list of data. How could I solve? Thanks all are gonna answer me. Best regards

Comment: You don't create XLS files with a `StreamWriter`, which is for plain text. There are some third-party libraries available for working with Excel files but I'm not sure that you'll find something free to write old-format (XLS) files. Generally speaking, you'll need Excel installed and to use Office Automation to save in that format. Anything else would be a lot of work. If you use the newer format (XLSX) then you have many more options and some free ones too. You can use OpenXML for that, so there's no need for Excel to be installed.

Comment: In the form I'm developing, in fact, I have a button to open data in excel (with excel application) but, since this application will be used from different users (for example using OpenOffice), OpenXML seems to be the best choice for this purpose. I'll try It and let you know.

Comment: Note that you can use OpenXML directly yourself, but there are also various third-party tools, often available as NuGet packages, that simplify it somewhat. I've never used any myself but one example is [ClosedXML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML).